# R: Creating new fields based on values in data frame list-columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I flattened a json file using `jsonlite` and ended up with list-columns containing a key field, which in my example data below I call "Clothes":

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4))
df$Things = list(list(Clothes = c("shirt","shoe","sock"), shapes = c("circle", "square")),
              list(Clothes = c("shirt","pant","jacket"), shapes = c("triangle", "circle")),
              list(Clothes = c("pant","belt"), shapes = c("pentagon", "square")),
              list(Clothes = c("shoe","scarf","sock"), shapes = c("circle", "pentagon")))
```

My goal is to pull out these values as new binary variables indicating whether each record contains each clothing items.  I'd also like to pull out these clothing items into separate columns, even while the clothing lists sometimes have different lengths.  As you can see, the list-column is two levels deep, with the Clothes list inside the Things list.

Here's what the sample output would look like:

```
dfOut <- mutate(df,belt = c(0,0,1,0),pant = c(0,1,1,0),shirt = c(1,1,0,0),
Clothes1 = c("shirt","shirt","pant","shoe"),
Clothes2 = c("shoe","pant","belt","scarf"),
Clothes3 = c("sock","jacket",NA,"sock"))
```

I assume the solutions would involve `dplyr::mutate()`, `purrr::map()`, `apply()`, or `ifelse()`.  I'd also appreciate help with the right terms/concepts so I can better ask these types of questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this to count up all of the clothes that occur in the `df$Things` list:

```
library(tidyverse)

# keep only Clothes, drop Shapes, and unlist for ease
df$Things <- purrr::map(df$Things, ~ .[1] %>% unlist)

# build a self-named vector of clothes types, for colnames from map_dfc()
all_clothes <- unique(unlist(df$Things)) %>% set_names(.)

# count occurances with grepl() and convert from bool to num
counts <- purrr::map_dfc(all_clothes, ~ as.numeric(grepl(., df$Things)))

# bolt it on
dplyr::bind_cols(df, counts)

  ID              Things shirt shoe sock pant jacket belt scarf
1  1   shirt, shoe, sock     1    1    1    0      0    0     0
2  2 shirt, pant, jacket     1    0    0    1      1    0     0
3  3          pant, belt     0    0    0    1      0    1     0
4  4   shoe, scarf, sock     0    1    1    0      0    0     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nate!  Applying your code helps me better understand purrr.

               Do you have an idea on my other strategy, to "Clothes1", "Clothes2", etc.?  It's essentially iterating over the list and creating a new field for each.  I'm trying to figure out if there a way for my code to flexibly create new fields regardless of whether the lists are length 2, 3 or 4, without writing a 1 to 5 for loop with error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple double loop to achieve first part of your task.

```
for (n in c("shirt", "scarf", "sock", "belt", "jacket","pant")) {
  for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
    df[[n]][i] <- ifelse(n %in% df$Things[[i]]$Clothes, 1, 0)
  }
}
df  

   ID      Things  shirt   scarf    sock    belt    jacket    pant   shoe
    1  1     shirt, shoe, sock, circle, square     1     0    1    0      0    0    1
    2  2 shirt, pant, jacket, triangle, circle     1     0    0    0      1    1    0
    3  3          pant, belt, pentagon, square     0     0    0    1      0    1    0
    4  4   shoe, scarf, sock, circle, pentagon     0     1    1    0      0    0    1
```

For the second part you could try something like that

```
Clothes <- unlist(df$Things)
Clothes <- data.frame(Name=attr(cl, "names"),Thing=cl)
for (j in 1:3) {
  assign( paste0("Clothes",j), 
           as.character( (Clothes %>% filter(Name == paste0("Clothes",j))) [,2]) )
}
Clothes2
[1] "shoe"  "pant"  "belt"  "scarf"
```

But it does not give *NA*s so it's not quite what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To do this task, how about first creating a 'tidy' dataframe (see http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/ for a 'tidy data' definition):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

tidy_df <- df %>%
  mutate(Clothes = map(Things, "Clothes")) %>%
  unnest(Clothes)
tidy_df

#>    ID Clothes
#> 1   1   shirt
#> 2   1    shoe
#> 3   1    sock
#> 4   2   shirt
#> 5   2    pant
#> 6   2  jacket
#> 7   3    pant
#> 8   3    belt
#> 9   4    shoe
#> 10  4   scarf
#> 11  4    sock
```

From there you can make the different components for the required output with `tidyr::spread`

```r
df1 <- tidy_df %>% 
  mutate(has_clothes = 1) %>%
  spread(Clothes, has_clothes, fill = 0)

df2 <- tidy_df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(rownum = paste0("Clothes", row_number())) %>%
  spread(rownum, Clothes)

left_join(df1, df2)

#> Joining, by = "ID"
#>   ID belt jacket pant scarf shirt shoe sock Clothes1 Clothes2 Clothes3
#> 1  1    0      0    0     0     1    1    1    shirt     shoe     sock
#> 2  2    0      1    1     0     1    0    0    shirt     pant   jacket
#> 3  3    1      0    1     0     0    0    0     pant     belt     <NA>
#> 4  4    0      0    0     1     0    1    1     shoe    scarf     sock
```

That is, the desired output `dfOut` can be obtained by:

```r
df %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "ID") %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "ID")
```